# Need help in HTML submit button and javascript(confirm-button) on django:

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Scenario: I'm trying to use image button in my HTML form with JavaScript:

```
<form method="post" name="delete">
<input type="image" name="{{a.id}}"
    src="http://localhost:8000/site_media/web/img/delete_icon.gif"
    onClick="decision(this,'Delete this Activity?','http://localhost:8000/delAct/listAct')"/>
</form>
```

this is my script:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
<!---
function decision(selectobject, message, url){
   if(confirm(message)) location.href = url+"/"+selectobject.name ;
}
// --->
</SCRIPT>
```

The problem is it's not redirecting to page `delAct/listAct` like it is supposed to do.  So I tried to change it to use `type="button"` and it's working fine:

```
<form method="post" name="delete">
<input type="button" name="{{a.id}}"
   onClick="decision(this,'Delete this Activity?','http://localhost:8000/delAct/listAct')"/>
</form>
```

My question is how to get the first script to work using `type="image"`? Is there any way to do that?

As an aside: I've try both `get` and `post` methods in the form already and it makes no difference. Also, I'm using Python 2.6 and Django in my project.

Comment: You seem to be using a Javascript reference that's at least ten years out of date. All caps tags? A `language` attribute? No `type` attribute? Comments to "hide" the script? Really, in 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that using an `input` of type image creates a submit button that looks like an image so when it is clicked the form is submitted to the same page you are on because the `<form>` tag doesn't specify an `action` attribute. To prevent the submit from trigering you need to return `false` from the decision event handler which will prevent the event from bubbling up.